# IBM BlueMix | While adding jsf : The application or context root for this request has not been found: ./?

Tags: java, jsf, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I have a simple JSF application running on IBM Bluemix working well with the following J2EE dependencies .

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

When replacing it with JSF dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the following error

The application or context root for this request has not been found: /

Any help?

My Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

  <display-name>Java DB Web Starter</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

  <persistence-context-ref>
    <persistence-context-ref-name>openjpa-todo/entitymanager</persistence-context-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>openjpa-todo</persistence-unit-name>
  </persistence-context-ref>

  <resource-ref>
    <!-- The cloudAutowiring-1.0 Liberty feature will resolve this to whatever 
         the database service name is -->
    <!-- When running locally without this feature, create a datasource with 
         the JNDI name "jdbc/mydbdatasource" in server.xml -->
    <!-- If using MySQL locally then use the "url" property and append "?relaxAutoCommit=true", for example: 
         <dataSource id='mysql-datasource' jdbcDriverRef='mysql-driver' jndiName='jdbc/mydbdatasource'> 
         <properties user='root' password='password' url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?relaxAutoCommit=true"/> 
         </dataSource> -->
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/mydbdatasource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
  </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Could you please specify which is the URL you are calling and the web.xml you are using on your jsf application?

Comment: @v.bontempi I updated the question with the web.xml ,, i am sorry i can't share the url because i made it worked now using the jee dependencies ....  i thnisk it will not add a value ! ... do you know why it works with with jee jar and not with jsf jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)

**Briefly**:

In case you're using Maven, you can find below the necessary coordinates:

**Java EE containers (WildFly, JBoss, TomEE, Payara, GlassFish, WebSphere, etc)**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version><!-- 7.0 (JSF 2.2) or 6.0 (JSF 2.0/2.1) --></version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note that the Java EE version must match the server's own Java EE version. You can't set it to 7.0 while targeting a Java EE 6 server.

**Servletcontainers (Tomcat, Jetty, etc)**

**Mojarra**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>// jsf-imp and jsf-api were been mereged into one jar 
    <version><!-- Check http://javaserverfaces.java.net --></version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also check org.glassfish:javax.faces repository for current latest Mojarra release version (which is 2.2.13 as of now).

**MyFaces**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
    <version><!-- Check http://myfaces.apache.org --></version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
    <version><!-- Check http://myfaces.apache.org --></version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking on your web.xml you should call your application using

*https://[your_application_URL]/faces/*

instead of

*https://[your_application_URL]/*

because the Faces Servlet is listening on this path according to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in the same way the jax-rs webservice is listening on the /api path according to

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Edit after chatting about the problem:

The problem is with the jsf dependency used, which makes the app to use the jsf-impl-xxx.jar containing classes under java package com.sun.faces, instead of the classes under the package javax.faces loaded with jsf-api-xxx.jar (used when using j2ee-web-api dependency)
The classes in this last jar are implementation of standard API defined by JSF specification.

If you would like to add only the dependency for JSF without taking with you the whole j2ee-web-api you could use the artifacts 
jsf-api-xxx as dependency

It will solve your problem

Comment: can you clarify the point  ? i am already using jee jar with same web.xml and it  works perfectly....

Comment: what do you mean with 'using jee jar with same web.xml'? Where is this application running?

Comment: kindly review my question .....the application is ruining on bluemix ,, jsf works only when using Jee dependency in pom file when use jsf dependency as mentioned in the question in  pom file it doesn't work .... and the two cases with same faces serlvet mapping in web.xml

Comment: I formatted your question, now the context is clear.
The problem is not JSF but the servlet you are configuring in your web.xml
Are you using the same web.xml when adding the JSF dependency?

Comment: The edit needs to be accepted. 
The problems is with your web.xml path configuration.

I cannot understand why you down-voted the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108953/discussion-between-ahmed-gamal-and-v-bontempi).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108962/discussion-between-ahmed-gamal-and-v-bontempi).